# PostgreSQL - tricky regular expression - what am I missing?

Tags: regex, postgresql

I have data as follows - please see the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=548c3f7e480cde6e8a2e2f7aa0b6b685) for all data and code below:

```
INSERT INTO t VALUES 

('|0|34| first zero'),
('|45|0| second zero'),
('|0|0| both zeroes');
```

I want to `SELECT` from the **start** of the line

- 1st character in the line is a piple (`|`)
- next characters are a valid (possibly negative - one minus sign) `INTEGER`
- after the valid `INT`, another pipe
- then another valid `INT`
- then a pipe

The rest of the line can be anything at all - including sequences with pipe, `INT`, pipe, `INT` - but these are **not** to be `SELECT`ed!

and I'm using a regex to try and `SELECT` the valid `INTEGER`s. A single ZERO is also a valid reading - `one ZERO and one ZERO only!`

The valid integers **must** be from between the first 3 pipe (`|`) characters and not elsewhere in the line - i.e.

```
^|3|3|adfasfadf |555|6666| -- tuple (3, 3) is valid
```

but

```
^|--567|-765| adfasdf     -- tuple (--567, -765) is invalid - two minus signs!
```

and

```
^|This is stuff.... |34|56|  -- tuple (34, 56) is invalid - doesn't start pipe, int, pipe, int!
```

Now, my regexes (so far) are as follows:

```
  SELECT
    SUBSTRING(a, '^\|(0{1}|[-+]?[1-9]{1}\d*)\|') AS n1,
    SUBSTRING(a, '^\|[-+]?[1-9]{1}\d*\|(0{1}|[-+]?[1-9]{1}\d*)\|') AS n2,
    a
  FROM t;
```

and the results I'm getting for my 3 records of interest are:

```
n1     n2     a
0    NULL     |0|34| first zero      -- don't want NULL, want 34
45      0     |45|0| second zero     -- OK!
0    NULL     |0|0| both zeroes      -- don't want NULL, want 0
3       3     |3|3| some stuff here
...
... other data snipped - but working OK!
...
```

Now, the reason why it works for the middle one is that I have `(0{1}|....` other parts of the regex in both the upper and lower one!

So, that means take 1 and only 1 zero OR... the other parts of the regex. Fine, I've got that much!

**However**, and this is the crux of my problem, when I try to change:

```
'^\|[-+]?[1-9]{1}\d*\|(0{1}|[-+]?[1-9]{1}\d*)\|'
```

to

```
 '^\|0{1}|[-+]?[1-9]{1}\d*\|(0{1}|[-+]?[1-9]{1}\d*)\|'
```

Notice the `0{1}|` bit I've added near the beginning of my regex - so, this should allow one and only one ZERO at the beginning of the second string (preceded by a pipe literal (`|`)) `OR` the rest... the pipe at the end of my 5 character snippet above in this case being part of the regex.

But the result I get is unchanged for the first 3 records - shown above, but it now messes up many records further down - one example a record like this:

```
|--567|-765|A test of bad negatives...
```

which obviously fails `(NULL, NULL)` in the first `SELECT` now returns `(NULL,-765)` for the second. If the first fails, I want the second to fail!

I'm at a loss to understand why adding `0{1}|`... should have this effect, and I'm also at a loss to understand why my `(0, NULL)`, `(45, 0)` and `(0, NULL`) don't give me `(0, 0)`, `(45, 0)` and `(0, 0`) as I would expect?

The `0{1}|` snippet appears to work fine in the capturing groups, but not outside - is this the problem? Is there a problem with PostgreSQL's regex implementation?

All I did was add a bit to the regex which said as well as what you've accepted before, please accept one and only one leading ZERO!

I have a feeling there's something about regexes I'm missing - so my question is as follows:

- could I please receive an explanation as to what's going on with my regex at the moment?
- could I please get a corrected regex that will work for `INTEGER`s as I've indicated. I know there are alternatives, but I'd like to get to the bottom of the mistake I'm making here and, finally
- is there an optimum/best method to achieve what I want using regexes? This one was sort of cobbled together and then added to as further necessary conditions became clearer.

I would want any answer(s) to work with the fiddle I've supplied.

Should you require any further information, please don't hesitate to ask! This is **not** a simple "`please give me a regex for INTs`" question - my primary interest is in fixing this one to gain understanding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some simplifications could be done to the patterns.

> ```
> SELECT
>   SUBSTRING(a, '^\|(0|[+-]?[1-9][0-9]*)\|[+-]?[0-9]+\|') AS n1,
>   SUBSTRING(a, '^\|[+-]?[0-9]+\|(0|[+-]?[1-9][0-9]*)\|') AS n2,
>   a
> FROM t;
> ```
>
> ```
> n1   | n2   | a                                                              
> :--- | :--- | :--------------------------------------------------------------
> 0    | 34   | |0|34| first zero                                              
> 45   | 0    | |45|0| second zero                                             
> 0    | 0    | |0|0| both zeroes                                              
> 3    | 3    | |3|3| some stuff here                                          
> null | null | |SE + 18.5D  some other stuff                                  
> -567 | -765 | |-567|-765|A test of negatives...                              
> null | null | |--567|-765|A test of bad negatives...                         
> null | null | |000|00|A test of zeroes...                                    
> 54   | 45   | |54|45| yet more stuff                                         
> 32   | 23   | |32|23| yet more |78|78| stuff                                 
> null | null | |This is more text |11|111|22222||| and stuff |||||||          
> null | null | |1  1|1  1  1|22222|                                           
> null | null | |71253412|ahgsdfhgasfghasf                                     
> null | null | |aadfsd|34|Fails if first fails - deliberate - Unix philosophy!
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=d970c550e8cfb4106ce1e8581fb0d7a7)*

Comment: Updated. Getting closer?

Comment: Yes, Luk, very much so! We're bang on on the numbers front - just lacking an explanation as to why my own additional snippet messed things up/didn't work?

Comment: maybe because the 1st regex in this solution also has 2 delimited parts?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand this part of the answer - why does this happen?

Comment: And anyway, it was the second regex that was problematic in my question - the first one was working fine?

Comment: Your 1st allows `|123|abc|`. And your 2nd would find (0,null) from `|0|123|`.  Btw, the current solution would still find (null, 123) from `|00|123|`